# How to get access token of an account to invoke google appscript apis programatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I would want to get the ID token to be consumed in google appscript web app (which needs my account) in order to access the API.

My end goal is to know how can I achieve `getGoogleIDTokenToInvokeAppScriptEndPoint` (I have added in my sample code).

What exactly needs to be done to programatically access ID Token to invoke AppScript APIs from external service.

I am not sure how to generate the same programatically. Do I need to create a service account on my behalf?

Lets say I created a google account as abc@gmail.com, so I need to access the service account programatically for this user only and not some other service account. I then want to get the ID token and invoke my appscript services using the same.

Here's what I have already done:

1. Created my doPost request and deployed it like this:
   [image]

Now the URL that I get can only be invoked if it has a bearer ${token}, where token is my ID token.

My question is how to possibly get this ID token programatically from an external service? I am using Node Application and I would like something like:

```
// External Script from where I am invoking AppScript API
const token = getGoogleIDTokenToInvokeAppScriptEndPoint();
// Now Since I got my ID Token, I could use the same
// to invoke my appScript app:
fetch(appScriptEndpoint, 
    {
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` // Token I got from first step
    }
}).then(res => res.json().then(data => data))
```

Here's how my appscript looks like (though not much relevant here, but still adding for detailing):

```
// AppScript Script
const doPost = (request = {}) => {
    const { _, postData: { contents, type } = {} } = request;
    let query = {};
    if (type === 'application/json') {
        query = JSON.parse(contents);
    } else if (type === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
        contents
            .split('&')
            .map((input) => input.split('='))
            .forEach(([key, value]) => {
                query[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
            });
    } else if (type === 'text/plain') {
        try {
            query = JSON.parse(contents);
        } catch (e) {
            return ContentService.createTextOutput(
                JSON.stringify({
                    error: true,
          statusCode: 400,
                    msg: 'Unable to Parse JSON',
                    type: type,
                    requestBody: contents,
          payload: {}
                })
            ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
        }
    } else
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({
                error: true,
        statusCode: 400,
                msg: 'Unknown Request Type',
                type: type,
        requestBody: contents,
        payload: {}
            })
        ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

    const apiKey = query.apiKey;
    const isAuthenticated = authenticate({apiKey});
  if(!isAuthenticated) return ContentService.createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({
                error: true,
        statusCode: 401,
                msg: 'User not authorized to make the Request.',
                type: type,
        requestBody: contents,
        payload: {}
            })
        ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  else {
    const {opType,opProps} = query;
    const result = requestHandler({opType, opProps});
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({
                error: false,
        statusCode: 200,
                msg: 'Connection Established',
                type: type,
        requestBody: contents,
        payload: result
            })
        ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
};
```

**Please note that I already know how to invoke it by keeping my web app open however, I want to invoke it when authentication is required as shown in the above configuration.**

Comment: Are you using OAuth?

Comment: I can use that, provided oAuth provides refresh token that can programatically regenerate my access/id tokens. At the moment I am struggling to understand how can I generate service account credentials that reflects my account and not any other service account

Comment: I managed to get an ID token from Apps Script with this article : https://medium.com/google-cloud/call-cloud-run-from-app-script-the-easy-way-70677086efa1

Comment: Hey thank you for the response, I manage to get id token from appscript too. However I am invoking an appscript api from another service and so I need to pass my idToken there as I have set the invoking rule in deployment as allow invoking only to `myself (My google account)`

Comment: Could you share an example of what you tried so far? It will be useful if you can as well provide more information about the specific API you are trying to use. Remember to always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo, extremely sorry for being vague. I have added all the details in the question, please let me know if you need more of it. My end goal is to know how can I achieve `getGoogleIDTokenToInvokeAppScriptEndPoint`. What exactly needs to be done to programatically access ID Token to invoke AppScript APIs from external service.